# Print pdf format problem for sheet music from Rosegarden

Tags: printing, pdf, music, rosegarden

I am trying to make sheet music on Ubuntu 18..04.1 LTS with [Rosegarden](https://www.rosegardenmusic.com/), and arranged the piece for treble and bass clefs with two grand piano tracks.

When I print the sheet music to PDF, the first line turns out fine, while the second line runs off the page and presumably would have the rest of the arrangement if the print area was wide enough.  I am not sure what is causing the issue.

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wUYsCHBTIZXyAJmuCIbK6BA1NEoQZ2FK/view?usp=sharing) to the file generated by Rosegarden.

Comment: Have you tried setting the page size in the printer settings? Please upload images to imgur.com then we can put those images in the question itself.

Comment: Please generate an example of the problem PDF, then screenshot it, save the screenshots, and then upload them to http://imgur.com and collect the URLs for each upload. Then, click [edit] and add the web links to the original question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Wkk0Teu       Sorry I took so long, I have been fairly busy.  I did notice that the timing is fairly off, but I think I'll be able to fix that on my own. @user68186